# Defining a resizable galleria in PrimeFaces

Tags: html, jsf-2, primefaces

Is there any way in primefaces3.0.1 (JSF2.0), using that I can define an galleria which is resizable w.r.t. screen dimension. Currently I am defining the galleria dimension in the following manner-

```
<p:galleria value="#{gallery.images}" var="image" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="250">
```

This is quite ok, however when I resize my browser, everything gets resized except the  galleria. At this time, the image contained by galleria is not resized , that is why covers other things. What should I do?

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same thing. i.e. using a galleria, which can contain pictures having size depends on the screen or galleria panel?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of **width** resize, you can make the .ui-galleria width attribute to 100%.

[How to resize primefaces galleria dynamically depending on the sorrounding div-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403637/how-to-resize-primefaces-galleria-dynamically-depending-on-the-sorrounding-div-c)

Comment: This is a solution for PrimeFaces 3.01?

Comment: Since PrimeFaces 3.0.1 has a ".ui-galleria", I presume so. But I didn't test it  on 3.0.1. I did it using 5.1.