# How to resize primefaces galleria dynamically depending on the sorrounding div-container

Tags: jsf, primefaces

(How) is it possible to dynamically resize primefaces galleria depending on the size of the sourrounding div-container? The galleria should allways fill the entire surrounding div-container.

Would be jscript/jquery the right approach?

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/galleria.jsf

Answer (score 2):

Try make the `.ui-galleria` width attribute to 100%. Make sure that  css class is relative.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The width attribute helped me out but I'm still having an issue with .ui-galleria-panel-wrapper because this class only accepts a height given in pixel. Further suggestions or am I missing a point?

Comment: Well, at moment i dont know how fit the height, but you can try the inverse, instead of define the height of div, define the height of galleria, and the height of div will be the content height. Note that, on width works too.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make both the gallery and the images inside fill the container, add in the css:

```
 .ui-panel-images {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.ui-galleria-panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also, add the following to the p-galleria element:
`panelWidth="auto"`

Comment: p-galleria is not tne PrimeFaces component but the prime-ng one. Please check if it workfor the PrimeFaces component too

Comment: panelWidth javax.el.ValueExpression 
(must evaluate to java.lang.Integer)

https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/galleria.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying something similar, and I also came to a problem.

I am using the p:galleria element like these:

```
<h:form id="galleriaForm" style="border: 2px solid blueviolet; min-height: 800px">
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid" style="border: 2px solid aqua; min-height: 100%">
                    <p:row style="display: inline-block; min-height: 800px;border: 2px solid green; min-width: 100%">
                        <p:column style="display: inline-block; min-height: 100%; min-width: 100%;border: 2px solid red">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Überschrift" style="display: block;"/>
                            <p:galleria value="#{ImageManager.layoutBauenBilderlsite}" 
                                        id="galleriaID"
                                        var="image" 
                                        showCaption="false" 
                                        transitionInterval="9000"
                                        effectSpeed="1500" 
                                        style="display: inline-block; min-width: 100%"
                                        effect="drop"
                                        panelHeight="">
                                <p:graphicImage url="resources/images/#{image}" 
                                                style="height: 1040px; border:1px dotted lightgray; margin-left: 30%"/>
                            </p:galleria>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

To change the panelHeight attribute the h:body uses onload to call a js function:

```
    function setGalleriaHeight(){
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    document.getElementById("galleriaForm:galleriaID").setAttribute("panelHeight", String(h));
}
```

The panelHeight attribute is set correctly, as I can see with my Browser, but the Element does not change.

To make sure that the attribute is correct I added it in my source code and it worked fine.

I also tried to set the the size as style="height: h" but then only the loaded image "p:graphicImage does not resize with.

Maybe there is someone to know why it does not change.